Command to start a service on a remote host (windows) using python
Command to start a service on a remote host (windows) using python.
New to python looking for commands the execute using python.
Commands to run on remote machine like start stop and other stuff on remote machine using python.

To manage services on a remote Windows, you can use modules such as pywinrm.
Here is an example of how you can use the module:
import winrm

def manage_service(remote_ip, username, password, service_name, action):
    """
    Manage a service on a remote Windows machine.
    ---
    :param remote_ip: IP address of the remote Windows machine.
    :param username: Username for authentication.
    :param password: Password for authentication.
    :param service_name: Name of the service to manage.
    :param action: Action to perform ('start', 'stop', 'status').
    """
    if action not in ['start', 'stop', 'status']:
        raise ValueError("Action must be one of: 'start', 'stop', 'status'")
    
    session = winrm.Session(remote_ip, auth=(username, password), transport='ntlm')
    
    command = {
        'start': f'sc start {service_name}',
        'stop': f'sc stop {service_name}',
        'status': f'sc query {service_name}'
    }[action]
    
    result = session.run_cmd(command)
    
    print(f"Output:\n{result.std_out.decode()}")
    if result.std_err:
        print(f"Errors:\n{result.std_err.decode()}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    remote_ip = ''
    username = ''
    password = ''
    service_name = ''

    manage_service(remote_ip, username, password, service_name, 'start')    # Start the service
    manage_service(remote_ip, username, password, service_name, 'stop')     # Stop the service
    manage_service(remote_ip, username, password, service_name, 'status')   # Check status


Thanks for your response but I cannot install winrm module as the python scripts executes from a Linux server.

you can install the module on the linux server
